# Write 2D array to PGM grayscale image

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d, pgm

I'm creating various 2D arrays of sizes from 100x100 to 2000x2000 elements. The values within the arrays can be clamped down to 0 - 255 gray scale and then need to be written to a PGM image in order to visually represent the data.

For example, I'm declaring the arrays globally as:

```
element case1[100][100];
```

element is a structure of `double pixelValue` and a Boolean value (that won't be used when actually writing to the file but is necessary in the program).

In writing to the PGM image, I am having errors considering the `FILE *fp` in this area of the code when writing after the header:

```
int *p 
for (int x = 0; x < dimension; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < dimension; y++)
    { //also doesn't work as: fp << (unsigned char)case1[x][y].pix; 
        int pix = case1[x][y].pixelValue; 
        *p = pix; 
        fp << (unsigned char)*p; 
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

I'm unsure of how to work with the pointer in order to get the `pixelValue` from each location within the 2D array. I need to be able to iterate through each `pixelValue` to get the visual representation of the data.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Used `fputc()` instead so that I could directly insert values instead of using pointers.